# lagging panel data with data.table

Tags: r, time-series, data.table

I currently lag panel data using `data.table` in the following manner:

```
require(data.table)
x <- data.table(id=1:10, t=rep(1:10, each=10), v=1:100)
setkey(x, id, t) #so that things are in increasing order
x[,lag_v:=c(NA, v[1:(length(v)-1)]),by=id]
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this?  I had found something online about cross-join, which makes sense.  However, a cross-join would generate a fairly large `data.table` for a large dataset so I am hesitant to use it.

Comment: `v[1:(length(v)-1)]` is dangerous (think about what would happen for an `id` with a single row). Using `head(v, -1)` as suggested below is the right thing to do.

Comment: yes, very good point! thank you.

Comment: i should just mention that in my code i do if (length(v)>1) {} .. but the `head` solution is certainly better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure this is that much different from your approach, but you can use the fact that `x` is keyed by `id`

```
x[J(1:10), lag_v := c(NA,head(v, -1)) ]
```

I have not tested whether this is faster than `by`, especially if it is already keyed.

Or, using the fact that `t` (don't use functions as variable names!) is the time id

```
x <- data.table(id=1:10, t=rep(1:10, each=10), v=1:100)
setkey(x, t)
replacing <- J(setdiff(x[, unique(t)],1))
x[replacing, lag_v := x[replacing, v][,v]]
```

but again, using a double join here seems inefficient

Comment: thanks! we'll see if anybody else has come up with something different

Comment: looks like this is the best way!